# How to change a value of a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following piece of code:

```
if (json.result=='OK') {
              message="Your correction has been added successfully";
             $("#ShoppingCartView.custom_terms_n_conditions/24").empty();
             $("#ShoppingCartView.custom_terms_n_conditions/24").html('123');
}
alert(message);
```

There is the problem: I can see alert with message, but the element with id="ShoppingCartView.custom_terms_n_conditions/24" doesn't change its value! This element exists really, and I don't understand why. Please, help me.

Comment: Also you do not need to call empty();

Comment: @JonTaylor nope, not valid at all. in jquery i think that invokes a line break.

Comment: For reference id's should match `[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_:.]*`

Comment: @Jon Taylor: HTML5 allows [more](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id-def).

Comment: @pimvdb although in HTML 5 as you pointed out it probably is safe to use it, I wouldn't say its safe to use it yet as a fully cross browser compliant id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to [escape](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) the `/` and `.` characters using two slashes. Also, `.html` will overwrite and thus empty already:

```
$("#ShoppingCartView\\.custom_terms_n_conditions\\/24").html("123");
```

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the OP `/` is not a valid character in a html id.

Comment: i think `custom_terms_n_conditions/24` is a class name.

Comment: @undefined: The OP uses `id="..."`.

Comment: @pimvdb although in HTML 5 as you pointed out it probably is safe to use it, I wouldn't say its safe to use it yet as a fully cross browser compliant id.

Comment: Thank you, it works. So, please, tell me, how can I escape a string programmatically?

Comment: @user1517541: Escaping is just a matter of prepending a ``\`` character. To produce that character, you have to escape itself as well: ``\\``. I'm not sure how you want it "programmatically".

Comment: Sorry, but I will use a variable instead of defined string; therefore I must escape it programmatically.

Comment: @user1517541: The docs specify the characters that need escape, so you could escape them all using: ``str.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~])/g, "\\$1")``.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code you just need to escape `/` with `\\`

```
if (json.result=='OK') {
              message="Your correction has been added successfully";
 $("#ShoppingCartView.custom_terms_n_conditions\\/24").html('123');
}
alert(message);
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I escape programmatically?